Inequalities. The method of rationalization.
Can someone explain me how to how to solve this task?
$\frac{log_x(2x^-1)log_x(2x^2)}{log_2x(x)log 2x^-2(x)}\ < 40$
Screen of an inequalitie
Well, I found the range of acceptable values.

$x > 0$
$x ≠ 0$
$\frac{2}{x}\ > 0$
$2x^2 > 0 => x ∈ R$
$x ≠ \frac{1}{2}\ $
$\frac{2}{x^2} ≠ 1\ => x ≠ ±\sqrt2\ $
$log_2x(x) ≠ 0$
$log_2x-2(x) ≠ 0$

I have brought everything to the same base $log_x$.
I brought similar terms, squared them and got this expression.
$(log^2_x(2)-1)(log^2_x(2)-4) < 40$
For convenience, I replaced $log^2_x(2)$ with another variable - t. And got this:
$log^2_x(2) = t$, where $t > 0$
$(t-1)(t-4)<40$
$t^2 - 5t-36 <0$
According to the inverse theorem of Viet, I get the following roots:
$t = -4$ and $t = 9$
$=> t ∈ (0;9)$
Next, I went back to the replacement and get the following expressions in the system:

$log^2_x(2)>0$ $=> log^2_x(2)>log_x(1) => 2 > 0$ -- FALSE. So, x Ø
$log^2_x(2)<9$ $=> log^2_x(2)-9 <0 => (log_x(2)-3)(log_x(2)+3)<0$

I've got a system.

$log_x(2)>-3$, $x ∈ R$
$log_x(2)<3$, $x = 2^\frac{1}{3} $

And I stuck. I don't know what to do next. I've got solution from the author of the task, but this is incomprehensible. Can somebody give me an advice how to solute it?

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.
